# не работает duration_cast в библиотеке chrono

Tags: c++, std-chrono

Я написал класс таймера.

`timer.cpp`:

```
#include "timer.h"
#include <cassert>
using namespace std::chrono;

Timer::Timer()
{

}

void Timer::start()
{
    t1 = steady_clock::now();
    started_now = true;
    started = true;
}

void Timer::stop()
{
    t2 = steady_clock::now();
    started_now = false;
}

void Timer::check()
{
    assert(started && "Timer didnt start");
}

duration<double> Timer::getTime()
{
#ifndef NDEBUG
        check();
#endif
     if (started_now)
         t2 = steady_clock::now();
     duration<double> elapsed_time = t2 - t1;
     return elapsed_time;

}

double Timer::getSeconds()
{
    auto time = getTime();
    duration<double> res = duration_cast<duration<double, std::ratio<1>>>(time);
    return res.count();
}

double Timer::getMilliseconds()
{
    auto time = getTime();
    duration<double> res = duration_cast<duration<double, std::milli>>(time);
    return res.count();
}
```

`timer.h`:

```
#pragma once
#include <chrono>


class Timer
{
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point t1;
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point t2;
    void check();
    std::chrono::duration<double> getTime();
public:
    bool started_now;
    bool started;

    Timer();
    void start();
    void stop();
    double getSeconds();
    double getMilliseconds();
};
```

`getSeconds` возвращает время в секундах, а `getMilliseconds` - в миллисекундах.
Почему эти функции возвращают одно и то же значение?

```
Timer timer = Timer();
timer.start();
/* ... */
timer.stop();
cout << "Seconds: " << timer.getSeconds() << endl;
cout << "Milliseconds: " << timer.getMilliseconds() << endl;
```

Вывод:

```
Seconds: 0.129542
Milliseconds: 0.129542
```

Comment: Если auto подставить то будут разные значения, он подставляет `std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>` в случае с 
`getMilliseconds` https://godbolt.org/z/z5MrP8nj7

Comment: Не понятно зачем вам нужен этот `double` в гетерах ? Можно же напрямую конвертировать
`duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(time).count();`

Comment: Я заменил auto на duration<double>, но ничего не изменилось. Я пишу double чтобы не урезалась дробная часть

Comment: `auto res` или `std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>  res` попробуйте, как в коде по ссылке

Comment: Спасибо, оно заработало